# node js post request

Tags: node.js, xmlhttprequest

[Success localhost response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf2Ps.png)

[Cannot GET /u/coupons at server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnXtj.png)

> Frontend script for post

```
<script>
var count = document.getElementById("count");
var len = document.getElementById("length");
var pattern = document.getElementById("pattern");

document.getElementById('coupons-button').onclick = function()
{
    if(count.value!=="" && len.value!=="")
    {
        const genReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
        let url = `count=${encodeURI(count.value)}&` +
                  `len=${encodeURI(len.value)}&` +
                  `pattern=${encodeURI(pattern.value)}`;

        genReq.open('POST',`/u/coupons?${url}`,true);
        genReq.send();

        genReq.onreadystatechange = e => {
            if(genReq.readyState === 4 && genReq.status === 200){
                let gen = JSON.parse(genReq.response);
                if (gen.state === "SUCCESS")
                {                         
                    var coupons = gen.coupons;
                    for(var i=0;i<coupons.length;i++)
                    {   
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        var text = document.createTextNode(coupons[i]);
                        div.appendChild(text);
                        document.getElementById('coupons-check').appendChild(div);
                    }

                } else {
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    var text = document.createTextNode("FAIL TO GENERATE");
                    div.appendChild(text);
                    document.getElementById('coupons-check').appendChild(div);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Server script

```
admin.post( '/u/coupons' ,(req,res)=>{
let params = getParameters(req);
  CouponWorker.generateCoupons({
      "len":decodeURI(params.len),
      "count":decodeURI(params.count),
      "pattern":decodeURI(params.pattern)
  }).then((_res) =>{
      console.log(_res)
      if(_res.success === true)
      {
          res.status(200).json({
              "state":"SUCCESS",
              "coupons":_res.coupons
          });
      }
      else{
          res.status(200).json({"state" : "FAILED"});
      }
  });
  });
```

> CouponWorker

```
const firebase = require('./Database');
const voucher_codes = require('voucher-code-generator');
exports.generateCoupons = function(params)
{
var len = params.len;
var count = params.count;
var pattern = params.pattern;

//pattern = pattern.replace(/1/g,'#');

const cpn_db = firebase.firebase.database();
var coupons;

return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    coupons = voucher_codes.generate({
        length:len,
        count:count,
        prefix:"AMP-",
        pattern: '####-####',
        charset:"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ"
    });
    if(coupons!==null)
    {
        for(var i =0;i<count;i++)
        {
            cpn_db.ref('coupons/cid-'+coupons[i]).set({
                "addedOn": getDateTime(),
                "code" : coupons[i],
                "amount" : 20,
                "expireDate" : null,
                "isActive" : true,
                "isDeleted":false
            });
        }
        resolve({
            "success":true,
            "coupons":coupons
        });
    }
    else
    {
        resolve({
            "success":false
        });
    }

});
}
```

Above given snaps shows the same code running on localhost and server,
localhost working fine,giving output and saving data to firbase while server response 404 not found resource.
I can not find the reason of this error.I tried url req on postman and responses are the same as above

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. It would be helpful for readers if you could take the relevant text/code from the images you've posted and include that in the post directly.